# QTableWidget verticalheader background color per line

Tags: c++, qt

I want to change the background color of a verticalheader. In my simple example it should just have two different colors.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image]

Code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    int rows = 2, cols = 3;

    tbl_widget = ui->tableWidget;
    tbl_widget->setRowCount(rows);
    tbl_widget->setColumnCount(cols);

    for(int rowCount = 0; rowCount < rows; rowCount++) {
        for(int colCount = 0; colCount < cols; colCount++) {
            QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("Text"));

            if((rowCount+colCount)%2 == 0) {
                newItem->setBackground(QColor(0, 200, 0, 60));               
            } else {
                newItem->setBackground(QColor(255, 255, 128, 70));               
            }
            tbl_widget->setItem(rowCount, colCount, newItem);
        }

        QTableWidgetItem *verticalItem = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(rowCount+1));
        if(rowCount%2 == 0) {
            verticalItem->setBackground(QColor(255, 255, 128, 70));
        } else {
            verticalItem->setBackground(QColor(0, 200, 0, 60));
        }
        tbl_widget->setVerticalHeaderItem(rowCount, verticalItem);
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I tried to develop it, but it seems like no change. Is it possible to change the background color of an vertical header item?

Comment: What do you mean there is no change? I notice that the setVerticalHeader has alternating colors.

Comment: That is strange. The first image is what I get on my machine. The second I photoshopped...

Comment: When you put **after** indicates that is what you have obtained, put an image of what you get, it worked for me. What is your OS?

Comment: Here's what I get with your code: https://imgur.com/a/jYmsz

Comment: I'm using a Win 7 x64

Comment: Try putting in the main.cpp: `a.setStyle("fusion");`

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much.